# Parse an xml data column on a table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

How do I parse an xml column on a table of data in SQL Server 2012

Sample data

```
<GetOfferAvailabilityResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p3="http://somewebsite.com/v2.0" xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/v2.0" p3:TransactionID="281234567">
    <p3:RuleResultList xsi:nil="true" />
    <p3:ResultList>
    <p3:ProviderResult p3:ProviderID="01" p3:ResultID="1234" p3:ResultType="NotAvailable" p3:ResultCode="NotAvailable" p3:BrokerID="55" p3:Structure="None">
    <p3:EntityState>None</p3:EntityState>
    <p3:ResultText>No Orders returned</p3:ResultText>
    <p3:ShortDescription>Not Available</p3:ShortDescription>
    <p3:LongDescription>We're sorry, but offers are currently not available for your service address.</p3:LongDescription>
    <p3:ResultAction>ErrorMessage</p3:ResultAction>
    <p3:SourceResultCode xsi:nil="true" />
        </p3:ProviderResult>
    </p3:ResultList>
    </GetOfferAvailabilityResponse>'
```

I tried:

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = 



DECLARE @test TABLE (ID INT, XmlRule XML)
Insert into @test VALUES(1,'
<GetOfferAvailabilityResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ---GetOfferAvailabilityResponse>')
```

When I use `Select @test.query ('\')` I get the entire xml but when I try `Select @test.query ('\GetOfferAvailabilityResponse')` I receive an empty result

Comment: Please provide something that you have tried which failed and we can attempt to help you figure out the problem. Otherwise, please read up on the spec, documentation, or blog posts regarding the topic to figure out what you might need to do.

Comment: You're **not respecting** the XML namespaces defined in your XML! See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @XmlTbl TABLE (ID INT, XMLDATA XML)

INSERT INTO @XmlTbl 
        ( ID, XMLDATA )
VALUES  ( 1, '<GetOfferAvailabilityResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p3="http://somewebsite.com/v2.0" xmlns="http://somewebsite.com/v2.0" p3:TransactionID="281234567">
    <p3:RuleResultList xsi:nil="true" />
    <p3:ResultList>
    <p3:ProviderResult p3:ProviderID="01" p3:ResultID="1234" p3:ResultType="NotAvailable" p3:ResultCode="NotAvailable" p3:BrokerID="55" p3:Structure="None">
    <p3:EntityState>None</p3:EntityState>
    <p3:ResultText>No Orders returned</p3:ResultText>
    <p3:ShortDescription>Not Available</p3:ShortDescription>
    <p3:LongDescription>We''re sorry, but offers are currently not available for your service address.</p3:LongDescription>
    <p3:ResultAction>ErrorMessage</p3:ResultAction>
    <p3:SourceResultCode xsi:nil="true" />
        </p3:ProviderResult>
    </p3:ResultList>
    </GetOfferAvailabilityResponse>')

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://somewebsite.com/v2.0' AS p3, DEFAULT 'http://somewebsite.com/v2.0')
SELECT
ProviderID = XmlData.value('(/GetOfferAvailabilityResponse/p3:ResultList/p3:ProviderResult/@p3:ProviderID)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    EntityState = XmlData.value('(/GetOfferAvailabilityResponse/p3:ResultList/p3:ProviderResult/p3:EntityState)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ResultText = XmlData.value('(/GetOfferAvailabilityResponse/p3:ResultList/p3:ProviderResult/p3:ResultText)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ShortDescription = XmlData.value('(/GetOfferAvailabilityResponse/p3:ResultList/p3:ProviderResult/p3:ShortDescription)[1]', 'varchar(250)'),
    LongDescription = XmlData.value('(/GetOfferAvailabilityResponse/p3:ResultList/p3:ProviderResult/p3:LongDescription)[1]', 'varchar(250)'),
    ResultAction = XmlData.value('(/GetOfferAvailabilityResponse/p3:ResultList/p3:ProviderResult/p3:ResultAction)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @XmlTbl
```

From a table that contains a column of type `XML`, select those bits and pieces that you need, taking into account the defined **XML namespaces** on your XML data

This gives me a result of:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marc, how to I parse the ProviderID, I tried and received NULL value -> ProviderID=XmlData.value('(/GetOfferAvailabilityResponse/p3:ResultList/p3:ProviderResult/p3:ProviderID)[1]','varchar(50)'),

Comment: @user3590494: added a line to fetch the `ProviderID` - since it's an **attribute** on a XML node, you must use the `@` symbol